# Why the Ei(x) pop up in Integration of ${e^{\frac{{ - \lambda x}}{{A - Bx}}}}$ by Mathematica?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

When I calculate the integration $\int {{e^{\frac{{ - \lambda x}}{{A - Bx}}}}} dx$ where $A,B,\lambda  > 0$ some how Mathematica return the $Ei(x)$ but do not show the step. Could anyone plase explain to me how to arrive at this result ?
Thank you for your enthusiasm  !
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that this start with
$$-\frac{\lambda  x}{A-B x}=t \implies x=\frac{A t}{B t-\lambda }\implies dx=-\frac{A \lambda }{(B t-\lambda )^2}$$ to make
$$I=-A \lambda\int \frac{  e^t}{(B t-\lambda)^2}\,dt$$
Then
$$t=\frac{\lambda -u}{B}\implies I=\frac{A \lambda  e^{\frac{\lambda }{B}}}{B}\int \frac{e^{-\frac{u}{B}}}{u^2}\,du$$ Now $u=B v$
$$I=\frac{A \lambda  e^{\frac{\lambda }{B}}}{B^2}\int \frac{e^{-v}}{ v^2}\,dv$$ Now, one integration by parts and you are done since
$$\int \frac{e^{-v}}{ v^2}\,dv=-\frac{e^{-v}}{v}-\text{Ei}(-v)$$

Comment: Oh thank you very much ! how could you come up with the ideas of $t = \frac{{\lambda  - u}}{B}$ ? and $u = Bv$

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh. The first, just to simplify the denominator.The second to have the simplest argument in the exponential. And third, 64 years of experience !! Cheers :-)

Comment: Oh now I understand your insight !