# Calculate (non elementary function is acceptable) $\int\limits_{x = D}^{x =\frac{A}{B}} {{e^{\frac{{-\lambda x}}{{A-Bx}}}}{e^{-Cx}}dx}$?

Tags: integration

I need to evaluate this integral as a follow up to a previous question, 
$\int\limits_{x = D}^{x = \frac{A}{B}} {{e^{\frac{{ - \lambda x}}{{A - Bx}}}}{e^{ - Cx}}dx} $ where $A,B,C,D,\lambda  > 0$ are all positive number that is greater than zero

[Why the Ei(x) pop up in Integration of ${e^{\frac{{ - \lambda x}}{{A - Bx}}}}$ by Mathematica?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3624731/why-the-eix-pop-up-in-integration-of-e-frac-lambda-xa-bx-b)

Thank you very much for your good will and enthusiasm !

Attempted effort do far has been unsuccessful because integration by parts make the problem look even more horrible

$\begin{array}{l}
u = {e^{ - Cx}} \Rightarrow u' =  - C{e^{ - Cx}}\\
v' = {e^{\frac{{ - \lambda x}}{{A - Bx}}}} \Rightarrow v = \frac{{ - A}}{B}{e^{\frac{{ - \lambda x}}{{A - Bx}}}} + x{e^{\frac{\lambda }{B} + \frac{{A\lambda }}{{B\left( {Bx - A} \right)}}}} - \frac{{A{e^{\frac{\lambda }{B}}}\lambda Ei\left( {\frac{{A\lambda }}{{B\left( {Bx - A} \right)}}} \right)}}{{{B^2}}}\\
\left. {uv} \right|_D^{\frac{A}{B}} - \int_{x = D}^{x = \frac{A}{B}} {\left[ { - C{e^{ - Cx}}} \right]} \left[ {\frac{{ - A}}{B}{e^{\frac{{ - \lambda x}}{{A - Bx}}}} + x{e^{\frac{\lambda }{B} + \frac{{A\lambda }}{{B\left( {Bx - A} \right)}}}} - \frac{{A{e^{\frac{\lambda }{B}}}\lambda Ei\left( {\frac{{A\lambda }}{{B\left( {Bx - A} \right)}}} \right)}}{{{B^2}}}} \right]dx
\end{array}$

Comment: What is the question here? What have you tried? What problem are you facing?

Comment: I don't believe there is a closed form without using some function defined as an integral, like $\mathrm{erf}$ or $\mathrm{Ei}$.

Comment: oh I mean a closeform in the form of non elementary function is also acceptable

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but the substitution $u = A-Bx$ yields
$$\int_{D}^{A/B} \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda x}{A-Bx} - Cx\right) \, dx
= \frac{1}{B}\int_0^{A-BD} \exp\left(- \frac{(Cu+\lambda)(A-u)}{Bu}\right) \, du$$

Comment: Is there any way to express this in term of special function because when I expand your substitution it boils down to integrate(u-1/u) du on some interval ?